# Get the top level comment ID

Tags: comments

How do I get the ID of the top level comment, as in, the **top parent** comment? Useful functions like `get_ancestors()` and `get_post_ancestors()` don't work with comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait? Did you just state `get_comment_ancestors()` does **not** exist? What were they thinking...

We can do this by looping through the entire comment thread until we find the top level comment. We identify it by `parent_comment` being set to `0`:

```
/**
 * Return the top parent comment ID
 * 
 * @param $comment_id
 * @return comment id
 */
function cc_get_top_level_comment_id_wpse_265978($comment_id){

    if (!is_numeric($comment_id)) return;

    $parent_comment_id = 1;

    // loop comment thread until we find the one which has parent comment ID set to 0
    while($parent_comment_id > 0) {
        $comment = get_comment($comment_id);
        $comment_current_id = $comment->comment_ID;
        $parent_comment_id = $comment->comment_parent;
        $comment_id = $parent_comment_id;
    }

    return $comment_current_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a really easy way to do this.

```
$comment = get_comment($id);
while($comment -> comment_parent != 0) {
  $comment = get_comment($comment_parent);
}
```

This will recursively track back up the ancestor tree until it returns the top level.